# Generate a CSV file from data with multiple tables in BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We need to generate a CSV file from data which resides in multiple tables in BigQuery.

Currently we are trying to build a java service which will fetch data in TableResult with help of google-cloud-bigquery package and collecting data in TableResult object and looping through it to create a CSV.
How fast and scalable this method is.

Or do we have any other option provided by GCP to accomplish this task.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to do so, is using build-in [BigQuery export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) to GCS mechanism, because BigQuery uses its parallelism to write the output using multiple threads. You can export up to 1 GB of table data to a single file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, use a [wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) to export the data into multiple files:

```
gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/csvfilename*.csv
```

Then, when all your `.csv` files are in Storage bucket, you can use `gsutil compose` command, which creates a new object whose content is the concatenation of a given sequence of source objects under the same bucket:

```
gsutil compose gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/a.csv gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/b.csv gs://<BUCKET_NAME>/composite.csv
```

where `composite.csv` is a concatenation of `a.csv` and `b.csv`. Please, refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose).

I hope it helps.

Comment: That was helpful. We used  BigQuery export and used Table.extract method to create CSV file in bucket itself. Can you let us know how we can export this csv to a ftp server

Comment: I was not finding where I can mark it as answer. Just marked . Thank you very much

Comment: I can help you, have you already created new question connected to export CSV to FTP server?

Comment: Yes Sir, you can share your opinions on that post

Comment: I will take a look on your case.